# Turtlebot driving to specifiy point with Twist

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

first of all i must excuse i messed up by posting this question wrong and it got to confusing so i delete it and post it correct again. A special excuse to jayess i messed up with copying my code correct he is fully right that at this point:

```
 if abs(angle_to_goal - theta) > 0.1:
            
        speed.linear.x = 0.0
        speed.angular.z = 0.1
```

Here needs to be bigger then 0.1 before here stands less...

So my question is how i can drive with my Turtlebot to a specific point or an array of points i give the robot. I am using Turtlebot package for ros kinetic and i run this in gazebo 7.0.

i tried this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Twist
from math import atan2
x = 0.0
y= 0.0
theta = 0.0
def newOdom(msg):
    global x
    global y
    global theta
    
    x = msg.pose.pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose.pose.position.y

    rot_q = msg.pose.pose.orientation
    (roll,pitch,theta) = euler_from_quaternion ([rot_q.x,rot_q.y,rot_q.z,rot_q.w])
rospy.init_node("speed_controller")
sub = rospy.Subscriber("/odom",Odometry,newOdom)
pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel_mux/input/navi', Twist, queue_size=1)
speed = Twist()
r = rospy.Rate(4)
goal = Point()
goal.x = 2
goal.y = 2
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    inc_x = goal.x - x
    inc_y = goal.y - y
    
    angle_to_goal = atan2(inc_y,inc_x)

    if abs(angle_to_goal - theta) > 0.1:
        
        speed.linear.x = 0.0
        speed.angular.z = 0.1
    else:
        speed.linear.x = 0.5
        speed.angular.z = 0.0

    pub.publish(speed)
    r.sleep()
```

So the program works for a few rotations but the turtlebot don´t reach the correct angle he drives most time before he reachs the correct angle and lands left of the target point.

I used this tutorial :

[tutorial to drive to specific point with twist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=259&v=eJ4QPrYqMlw)

He used same controller and the robot drives perfectly as he should... Only difference i use a turtlebot for it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278778/turtlebot-driving-to-specifiy-point-with-twist/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-04**:
In the future, please don't delete a question because "it got messy"

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-04**:
You can always edit the question to clean it up.

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-01-04**:
Okay i am sorry... In the future I will do . So I hope now the problem is better to understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be an error through odometry... the odometry wasn´t correct i resetet world and robot position and now it works...

---

Originally posted by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) with karma: 206 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0